# What is the overall point of Gibson's "Burning Chrome" short story?

Tags: william-gibson, burning-chrome

I'm taking a really intensive sci-fi themed college writing course.  I have a paper analyzing this story.

This a good short story.  I liked reading it.  I can pick out a lot of the conflicts and themes, but... I cannot for the life of me pick out the main idea/point of this story.

What is the point?  What was he even trying to say?

Comment: This seem to be too broad as it's basically asking for opinions.

Comment: If your professor assigned this yesterday, I'll print out this web page and eat it. If he didn't, you should have made a try, written the best you could have, and posted that and asked for whether it's correct. Otherwise, it looks (deservedly or not) like you are trying to get people to do your assignment for you, which is typically frowned upon on many SE sites.

Comment: Having said that, "Burning Chrome" is AFAIK a collection of stories. As a collection, it may not necessarily have a central idea/point.

Comment: @DVK Burning Chrome is one of the stories in the Burning Chrome collection.

Answer (score 4):

- First of all, we can learn what the point was from 1992 ["burning chrome" essay/review by Lance Olsen](http://www.lanceolsen.com/burningchrome.html). In it, he covers two ideas:

  1. The story - like some others in the Burning Chrome collection, but even more pronounced - sets the stage for his Matrix trilogy (especially *Neuromancer* etc...). The story heroes and setting and ideas are prototypes for later work - Olsen calls it a "blueprint" for *Neuromancer*.
  2. The main theme of the story is, according to Olsen, "**betrayal, violation, and manipulation**" (which I fully agree with, having read it).

---

- While we can agree or argue with Olsen's interpretation, we can always listen to what the man himself said. In 2002, Gibson published an ["author's essay" on Harper Collins website](http://www.harpercollins.com/author/authorExtra.aspx?authorID=25692&isbn13=9780060539825&displayType=bookessay) (**Dead link)**, titled **"William Gibson on Burning Chrome: SOURCE CODE"**. In it, Gibson confirms explicitly the precursorship to Neuromancer:

  > Within it gun the engines of Neuromancer...

---

- Further discussion of Burning Chrime can be found [on Literature in a Wired World Wikia](http://litinawiredworld.wikia.com/wiki/Burning_Chrome), specifically "Literary Analysis" section. According to their quite extensive analysis, the main themes are:

  1. Love and Loss.
  2. The consuming nature of technology in our lives; being lost in the technology.